# Exercises to prepare you for high altitude sickness

Tags: mountaineering, high-altitude, exercises

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Training to prepare for oxygen deficiency in the high mountains](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/training-to-prepare-for-oxygen-deficiency-in-the-high-mountains)

My girlfriend and I are looking to do a portion of the Annapurna pass (Jomsom trek). She has climbed Kilimanjaro (not without difficulty) 3 years ago and I am a beginner with basic hiking experience in Himalayas.
My question is what are some good gym exercises to prepare for a 8 day trek in Himalayas? We go a max height of 5000m at thorung la pass.
Are there exercises specifically to train you for lack of oxygen? Or does any aerobic exercise(running,biking,swimming) count?

Comment: also: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/464/what-are-some-proven-methods-of-training-for-week-long-backpacking-trips-in-high